# How can I use testcafe to intercept and mock websocket requests

Tags: javascript, websocket, mocking, automated-tests, testcafe

I am trying to override some websockets requests for functional testing purposes.

I have tried using intercepts and mocking as advised here https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/ however this only seems straightforward for HTTP and can only update status code in WSS. The messages in the WSS is in JSON which I need to override.

```
import { RequestMock } from 'testcafe';
import { debug } from 'util';


const mockStream = new RegExp('test\/socket.io\/v2\/.?');

const ipUrl = 'https://example.com';
const mockedResponse = Buffer.from([0x47, 0x49, 0x46, 0x38, 0x39, 0x61, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01]);

const mock = RequestMock()
    .onRequestTo(mockStream)
    .respond(mockedResponse, 101, {
        'access-control-allow-credentials': true,
    });

fixture `Fixture`
    .page(ipUrl)
    .requestHooks(mock);
test('Mocking', async t => {
    await t
    .debug()
        .click('#button')
        .wait(5000)
        .debug();
});
```

Comment: You should add your code attempts for us to be able to help you.

Comment: I have added it. I assumed it wont be required.

Comment: i'll take a look later. You should checkout this guideline https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Following these steps will help you get better answers.

Answer (score 4):

At present, it's not possible to intercept WebSocket requests.
I've created an [issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3832) for this case in the TestCafe repository. 
Track it to be informed about our progress with implementing this feature.

Comment: How is the situation with this

Comment: It is not implemented yet. You can track the issue at https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3832